`C-h m` help doesn't show global minor modes?
I want to define a minor mode whose global arg is set to t. To make sure the mode is actually active, I call describe-mode by typing C-h m. However, as soon as I add :global t the mode does not show in the list of active modes.
Here comes a minimal working example
(define-minor-mode test-mode
  " this is a test mode"
  ;; The initial value.
  nil
  ;; The indicator for the mode line.
  " test"
  ;; The minor mode bindings.
  nil)

(test-mode 1)

if I evaluate the above lines, "Test" appears in the list of active modes displayed by evaluating C-h m.
In contrast, when I evaluate
(define-minor-mode test-mode
  " this is a test mode"
  ;; The initial value.
  nil
  ;; The indicator for the mode line.
  " test"
  ;; The minor mode bindings.
  nil
  ;; Keyword args
  :global t)

(test-mode 1)

then I don't see "Test" in the list of active minor modes.

* Changes in Emacs 29.1

*** The 'C-h m' ('describe-mode') "*Help*" buffer has been reformatted.
It now only includes local minor modes at the start, and the global
minor modes are listed after the major mode.

Look for Global minor modes enabled: in the help buffer.

Good to know. I can understand why they moved all of that global minor mode doc to the end, but they should also have said, up front (where it lists the local minor modes) that global minor modes are described at the end. Poor UI.

Yeah, it doesn't seem ideal.  At least the buffer has page breaks, so if you C-x ] then the global mode info (being at the end of that first page) is just above.

https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=2473 is the reason for that change, and https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=64684 seems relevant as well.  (With the latter these lists are gone completely from the UI; but you can S-TAB to collapse all the sections down to their headings -- which is then a list of all the enabled modes.)

Good to know the culprits. I think we agree that how/where to see such info should be pointed out at the top. It's too easy to read "Minor modes enabled in this buffer" as being the only description of the minor modes that are enabled. Global minor modes are also enabled in the buffer, and they're not listed there. IOW (1) Say "Local minor modes"... (not "Minor modes enabled in this buffer"), and (2) tell users where to see the info about the enabled global minor modes.

In the list of global minor modes, however, it seems the modes are displayed according to the names and not according to the 'indicator for the mode line' variable, aren't they? At least changing this variable didn't change the how the mode was listed in the list of global minor modes.

Olmo: The lighter text (mode line indicator) isn't reliable -- modes don't have to display anything at all in the mode line, and when they do it's liable to be something very brief (often a few characters at most).  It's not appropriate to use in a comprehensive list of enabled modes.
